# git repository in window server 2008 cannot clone to local with ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh

**I am now trying to do git repository in server with ssh and I cannot clone  it to my local.
My IP is 103.244.89.55  and use ssh with bitvise ssh server.**
[image]
[image]

**i used git to init in "C:xampp/htdoc/maya" folder**

[image: I use]
[image]

**And i cannot clone to my local from server,please**

[image]

Comment: you got solution ?

Comment: You need to add 'sudo ' while working in terminal. it is the equivantlent of run as adminsitor in windows!

Comment: yes, would you like me to expand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your username and email in the commandline git so it can  access github, for example at the shell prompt:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Richard E. Silverman"
$ git config --global user.email res@oreilly.com
```

After those are set you should be all set.

---

- comment response

In that case if you want to install it the same configuration as above you need to run Powershell or bash on unbuntu on windows, or whatever shell that is, as Administrator to give you access rights to the install directory.

Comment: I am trying to do without using github. just only from server and client. please.